# Android Device Manager System image download error

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, android-emulator

I just downloaded Xamarin in Visual. Following some basic tutorials, I made a blank Mobile App and tried using the emulator but whenever I try downloading a new device after some point in the download I get the

> System image download error. The decryption operation failed, see inner exception.

I tried reinstalling the whole Visual Studio but it doesn't help either.

Comment: Why do you not follow the exception message and take a look at the inner exception?

Comment: @UweKeim how? Sorry, im new to xamarin so i have no idea where to see the inner exception, nothing appears on the screen besides the "The decryption operation failed, see inner exception."
error message.

Comment: This error has been reported and be fixed in VS 16.5 Preview 3. Please check the link below. https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/518394/android-device-manager-system-image-download-error.html

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT even after instaling the preview version i get this error

Comment: @tng_89 Check the requirements for the Android device. Maybe you miss something. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/device-manager?tabs=windows&pivots=windows

Comment: I had the same problem, but when I downloaded another device like Pixel C Pie 9.0 - API 28. It worked, and the default Pixel 2 was not getting downloaded.